# aws cli s3 sync, exclude not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to sync data from ec2 to s3 bucket with exclude option

```
root@ir:ls /data/
f1 f2 f3 
root@ir:aws s3 sync /data/ s3://data/ --profile s3to --exclude "/data/f1/*"
root@ir:aws s3 sync /data/ s3://data/ --profile s3to --exclude "/data/f1/"
root@ir:aws s3 sync /data/ s3://data/ --profile s3to --exclude "/data/f1*"
root@ir:aws s3 sync /data/ s3://data/ --profile s3to --exclude "f1/*"

root@ir:aws --version
aws-cli/1.9.15 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-48-generic botocore/1.3.15
```

But none of above options work and f1 continues to sync to the S3 bucket.

Comment: I recall I  read it somewhere that, you must use both --include and --exclude. Can you try --include *  --exclude "/data/f1"   ,etc.

Comment: @mootmoot, its the other way around ... by default, all files are included. This means that providing only an `--include` filter will not change what files are transferred. it will only re-include files that have been excluded from an `--exclude` filter. If you want only want to upload files with a particular extension, you need to first exclude all files, then re-include the files with the particular extension.

Answer (score 10):

None of the answers are explicitly stating *why* the `--exclude` parameter was seemingly not working.

#### The Why

`--exclude` uses a relative path to the directory being sync'd.

For example, the following fails because the `sync` command is syncing the `/data/` directory, and the `--exclude` parameter is an absolute path.

```
aws s3 sync /data/ s3://data/ --exclude "/data/f1/*"
```

The solution is to use a relative path from the folder being sync'd to the folder being excluded with the `--exclude` parameter:

```
aws s3 sync /data/ s3://data/ --exclude "f1/*"
```

#### Note The Differences

```
   Fails: --exclude "/data/f1/*"
Succeeds: --exclude "f1/*"
```

Answer (score 3):

can you try

```
aws s3 sync /data/ s3://data/ --profile s3to --exclude "*f1/*"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need `--delete` if the file is already there.

Comment: This was my case, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
aws s3 sync /home/ec2-user/folder s3://my-bucket --exclude "f1/*"
```

Example:

```
$ ls -l
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Apr 23 00:42 f1
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Apr 23 00:42 f2
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Apr 23 00:42 f3

$ aws s3 sync /home/ec2-user/folder s3://my-bucket --exclude "f1/*"
upload: f2/foo to s3://my-bucket/f2/foo
upload: f3/foo to s3://my-bucket/f3/foo
```

Comment: I have tested, with 3 folder like you mentioned in your comment, and it is working file.  but it is not working on my production environment. In production folder f2 is already sync, now i want to exclude it, but it still sync on s3.

Comment: Does it show (in the output) that it is still syncing f2, or do you mean that it is not deleting f2 in the remote location?